# PhpMyAdmin export table result query with alias'

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

#### Scenario

I'm trying to move products from an old database table into a new one with different column names. I am selecting the columns I need and using alias' to change the names of existing columns to match the new database table and also to create new columns with dummy data for columns that don't exist in the old database table.

#### Problem

When I use the export button at the bottom of the page, the columns aren't using the new names and some of my new columns are missing a name if the data is a blank string.

#### Example Query

```
SELECT
    old_name AS new_name,
    '' AS new_column_1,
    42 AS new_column_2 
FROM 
    table
```

#### Example Exported SQL File

```
INSERT INTO `table` (`old_name`, , `new_column_2`) VALUES
('Test 1', '', 42),
('Test 2', '', 42);
```

Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong or provide a working solution?

Comment: You have to provide a column name for the second column in your `INSERT` statement. I am surprised that you did not get syntax errors.

Comment: @JayBlanchard This works for the query result set. I see a new column with the name 'new_column_1' with an empty value which is what I want. Maybe it's just a bit of a hack. Do you know how I would do a similar thing?

Comment: That seems a bit weird, the new table actually has three columns with column names?

Comment: Are you referring to the second example? That is a section of the exported result set. I updated the question to make that more clear.

Comment: Instead of doing this manually, have you seen the relatively new phpMyAdmin feature to "Rename exported databases/tables/columns" -- from the export page (which exists starting with phpMyAdmin 4.3.0)?